# getting two lists into a multiindexed pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have two lists `a` and `b` built with list comprehension. They have equal length. E.g.: `a = [1, 2, 3]` and `b = ['a', 'b', 'c']`.

Now, I want to have a pandas MultiIndex Series with the data from these lists. E.g.:

```
2017-03-31  num    1
            lab    a
2017-04-30  num    2
            lab    b
2017-05-31  num    3
            lab    c
```

Right now, I'm doing this as follows:

```
from itertools import chain
daterange = pd.date_range('2017-03', '2017-06', freq='M')
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([daterange, ['num', 'lab']])
series = pd.Series(list(chain(*zip(a, b))), index=index)
```

This works fine, but for some reason it feels 'ugly' to me. First, I'm disappointed that I need to add the explicit `list` statement, since pandas seems to interpret the chain object as a scalar instead of an iterator, but I also don't like to import itertools for just this.

So, is there a better way? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put your data together as a DataFrame and then `unstack` it into a series which should give you the shape you want:

```
daterange = pd.date_range('2017-03', '2017-06', freq='M')
df = pd.DataFrame([a,b], index=['num', 'lab'], columns=daterange)
```

This makes a 2x3 dataframe:

```
print(df)

    2017-03-31 2017-04-30 2017-05-31
num          1          2          3
lab          a          b          c

series = df.unstack()
```

This reshapes your `DataFrame` to a `Series` with your `MultiIndex` as its index

```
print(series)

2017-03-31  num    1
            lab    a
2017-04-30  num    2
            lab    b
2017-05-31  num    3
            lab    c
```

Comment: Ah! This seems to do the trick indeed. It seems a little bit slower that my example (real situation is of course more complex and large than the example I derived for my question), but it's definitely much cleaner. Thanks a lot!